# ngFor not updating in IE 11 (RC4 with CoreJS)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angular

First of all, i took a look in all existing questions regarding angular and IE on stackoverflow as well on the git repo of angular itself in the issues section. Couldn't find anything that helped me, so this is definitily not a duplicate (there are many problems with IE and ng2 regarding shims, which should be resolved with using `CoreJS`).

I have a problem with Angular (RC4) in IE 11 (probably lower versions as well) with using `*ngFor`.

I have a List Component, which holds an array of `listData` (an array of objects provided via `@Input()`).

Additionally i have a directive (something like a lazy-loader), which observes scroll position and calls a backend method if a specific point is reached (think of an infinite scroll directive).

In my main view i use this list component with the directive attached and control it from this main component.

I try to simplify the components / directives as much as possible:

The scroll directive doesn't do much at this point, it has an native event listener attached to the `window.scroll` event, checks the parent components dimensions and calls a backend method provided via `@Input` from the `main component` and emits and event with the loaded data after its done loading.

As i already mentioned the ListView Component holds a reference to the whole data (initialized by the main component).

my Main Component:

```
export class MyMainComponent {
    @ViewChild(ListViewComponent) listView: ListViewComponent;

    listData: any[];

    constructor(private _zone: NgZone) {
        this.getBackendDataMocked().subscribe((arr) => {
            this.listData = arr;
        });
    }

    onLazyLoadComplete(loadedData: any[]) {
        // this._zone.run(() => { // todo: ie11 and below fix.
            for (let item of loadedData) {
                this.listData.push(item);
            }
        // });
        this.listView.refresh();
    }
}
```

The template initializes both the listView and the directive something like this:

```
<list-view *ngIf="listData"
     lazy-loader
     [doLazyLoad]="getBackendDataMocked()"
     (onLazyLoadStart)="onLazyLoadStart($event)"
     (onLazyLoadComplete)="onLazyLoadComplete($event)"
     [listData]="listData">
</list-view>
```

In my listView Template i use *ngFor to display the `listData`. Actually, i use `ngFor` with `template` but this doesn't make a difference for my problem.

It works fine in most browsers (chrome, firefox, safari, edge, vivaldi...) but not in IE11. I **don't get any error messages** at all, the list does initialize correctly.
If i scroll down the `onLazyLoadComplete` **function is fired correctly**, **the array is populated correctly**, the listView updates correctly but the changes aren't reflected in my view. Nothing happens.

Now to the **BUT**: As you can see in the code i provided up top, i tried wrapping the `for loop` in my `onLazyLoadComplete` function with `zone.run( () => { })` which actually works. The problem is, i don't know why this makes a difference and i actually don't know if there are downsides of doing this. (I think it slows down performance actually) but at least it works in IE11 then.

Even something like this would do the trick for me:

```
onLazyLoadComplete(loadedData: any[]) {
    for (let item of loadedData) {
         this.listData.push(item);
    }
    this._zone.run(() => { // todo: ie11 and below fix.
         this.listData = this.listData;
    });
    this.listView.refresh();
}
```

But well, no way i'm doing that.

My index.html (regarding shims, order of imports etc) looks like this:

```
<script src="src/vendor/node_modules/shim.min.js"></script> // core js
<script src="src/vendor/node_modules/system.src.js"></script> 
<script src="src/vendor/node_modules/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="src/vendor/node_modules/zone.js"></script>
```

Changing the order of the script tags, adding `es6-shim`, adding `shims-for-ie.js` (Which is mentioned somewhere as well). Nothing makes a difference (well it obviously does, but not for this problem).

One last thing: Since the `zone.run` stuff actually works, i thought it has something to do with an event listener i added in my listView using `zone.runOutsideAngular()` but it doesn't. If i remove the `runOutsideAngular` call performance will go down and it doesn't fix my problem. I have to say, i haven't figured out the whole `zone.js` stuff yet...

Any help would be so much appreciated. If i should provide more code, please ask in the comment and i will do it, but i think this should be enough.

Comment: How do you listen to the scroll event?

Comment: Native event listener window.addEventlistener. No difference using HostListener.

Comment: If using `HostListener` doesn't fix it I don't understand why `zone.run(...)` helps.

Comment: I will try again to be sure.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Damnit, i changed the wrong listeners...Changing from `window.addEventListener` to `@HostListener('window:scroll')...` solves it. I focused on the scroll event in my listview instead of my directive... Performance seems to be the same, at least `ngOnChanges` is fired the same amount of times on scroll. Well thank you so much. I could kill my self right now for missing this. i thought i actually did the exact test yesterday...

Comment: It least you got it working now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
@HostListener('window:scroll'/*, ['$event']*/)
eventHandler(/*event) {
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
window.addEventListener
```

Comment: Thanks again. Frustrating...my thought was "okay, have to use window.scroll instead of `@HostListener` inside `runOutsideAngular()` in my listComponent otherwise `ngOnChanges` is fired endlessly in my attached directive and to keep consistency, i also changed it to `window.addEventListener` in my directive...